# Select custom post field (ACF) from wordpress posts

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created a custom post type : stock

In stock, I have add a lot of custom field with ACF.

I created maybe 20 stock.

Now, I'm trying to get the values of the different custom field (in workbench) for each post.

Here some field : prix (price), ville (city), nombre de chambres (number of rooms)

The result I want :

```
post_title | prix | ville | nombre de chambres
Title 1    | 20   | paris | 3
Title 2    | 40   | marseille| 4
Title 3    | 30   | royan| 2
etc...
```

The code I tried :

```
SELECT post_title,
(select meta_value from mod803_postmeta where meta_key = 'prix')
FROM mod803_posts
WHERE post_type='stock' AND post_status='publish'
```

I get the title and a column named : "select meta_value from mod803_postmeta where meta_key = 'prix'" but the column is 'NULL'.

Thank you

Comment: So I'm still looking for some answer.

Comment: I found how to access to my meta value : 

    SELECT * FROM mod803_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE ('ville')  AND post_id=4401
    UNION SELECT * FROM mod803_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE ('Prix_de_vente')  
    AND post_id=4401

Now I'm trying to connect it with my post id.

Comment: SELECT * FROM mod803_postmeta WHERE post_id=4401

Here I get all the custom field.

But Now I'm not able to join it with my "post_title" in the posts table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here the solution for get WP POST with CUSTOM POST TYPE AND ACF FIELDS :

```
SELECT ID, p.post_title as 'Post Title', t.name as 'Category', p.post_date as 
"Post Date", p.post_name as "Post Name" , m2.meta_value AS "Prix", m4.meta_value 
AS "Surface"
FROM mod803_posts p, mod803_terms t, mod803_term_relationships tr, 
mod803_term_taxonomy tx, mod803_postmeta m2, mod803_postmeta m4
WHERE p.post_type = 'stock'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND tx.taxonomy = 'typedestock'
AND p.ID = tr.object_id
AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
AND tx.term_id = t.term_id
AND m2.post_id = p.id AND m2.meta_key = 'Prix de vente'
AND m2.post_id = p.id AND m4.meta_key = 'Surface'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).